# How do I use node's debug module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I use `debug`? [Reading the debug docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) I get:

> With debug you simply invoke the exported function to generate your debug function, passing it a name which will determine if a noop function is returned, or a decorated console.error, so all of the console format string goodies you're used to work fine.

Ok, the debug module exports a single function, I understand. But this part seems to be missing something:

"That function takes a `name` which will determine if a noop function is returned, or a decorated console.error"

OK. I gather `name` is a String, so what String value determines if a no-op is returned, or a decorated console.error? I would like the console error, as no-op seems to be the default.

I have a module that uses debug. It's currently set up like;

```
var debug = require('debug')('module-name');
```

And it's completely quiet. I would like debug to be be turned on. **What String value should I use to enable debug?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So `debug` basically has an on-off switch but it's not in your javascript code, it's in the `DEBUG` environment variable value. So if you wanted to turn on debugging for your sample snippet you would do:

In bash:

```
export DEBUG=module-name
node myapp.js
```

In powershell:

```
$env:DEBUG = 'module-name'
node myapp.js
```

Debugging is off by default, so if you `unset DEBUG` in your shell, nothing will be output.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! The docs do actually have an example of this, they just take their sweet time getting to the important stuff.